# Nested Sass not Working?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I can't for the life of me figure out why this nested sass is not working. Here's my html:

```
%h1 Office Listing
#office-holder
  .listing-stats··
    #address·
      =@office_listing.address
    .listing-stats-2
      #rent
        %span.special2 Rent:·
        $#{@office_listing.rent}/month
      #size
        %span.special2 Space:·
        #{@office_listing.size} sq. feet
```

This is all within a div that namespaces the html page, which has two ids -- #office_listing and #show. I'm using rails, so I'm using the namespaces to neatly separate the views for my css. Here's the CSS that isn't working:

```
#office_listing#show {
  #address {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #A0183C;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Yet the CSS for that isn't displaying. The CSS seems to be compiling fine, however. When I inspect the compiled stylesheets, they look like this:

```
#office_listings#show #address {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #A0183C;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  color: white; }
```

Which seems like it should target the appropriate HTML element. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you have double ids? `#office_listings#show` implies that you have two ids on the same element. That's against convention and my guess is that it just won't match. Make `show` a class instead and have `#office_listings.show #address` instead

Comment: Interesting. That actually worked even though I have an identical double id setup for other pages and they seem to be working fine. Hmm... The class approach seems cleaner anyway so I'll go with it, but I'm still curious as to why that rule seems to be applied inconsistently.

Comment: If you attempt to validate an HTML document where you have an element with multiple ids (`<div id="foo bar" />`), it fails.  So no, it is not allowed.  Expect the unexpected with invalid HTML.